# Plot edge labels or similar with Igraph for Python

Tags: python, label, igraph, edges

I would like simply to plot labels not to the vertex of the graph but to the edge.

Simple enough case: Kamada Kawai layout for undirected graph.

I'm fantasizing about something like this:

```
visual_style["edge_label"] = g.es["weightthing"]
```

To try to justify my question as I was researching much but found only this:

> The edge labels. They will be converted to character. Specify NA
>   to omit edge labels.
>
> Edge labels are omitted by default.

from [here](http://igraph.sourceforge.net/doc/R/plot.common.html%20#I%20see%20it%27s%20for%20R%20but%20probably%20the%20same%20case%20for%20Python)

I fail to understand the above quote. Sorry.

- Is it possible to plot label to edge?
- Aprox. how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately edge labels are not supported yet in the Python interface of igraph. (By the way, you were reading the documentation for the R interface).

**Update**: the development version of igraph (i.e. version 0.7) now supports edge labels.

Comment: No problem. I will use that edge_width and edge_color to highlight visually what I want. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NetworkX](http://networkx.github.io/) instead. 
(EDIT) You may like to use this function:

```
networkx.draw_networkx_edge_labels()
```

The docstring shows the use of the parameter `edge_labels`:

```
edge_labels : dictionary
       Edge labels in a dictionary keyed by edge two-tuple of text
       labels (default=None). Only labels for the keys in the dictionary
       are drawn.
```